# Can someone help me with this sets question? (How many students knew no coding language?)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

Q:
In a survey of a group of 100 computing students, it was found that
32 knew Java, 33 knew C, 32 knew Python,
5 knew both Java and C, 7 knew both C and Python while none of the
students knew both Java and Python. How many students knew none of
the three languages?

> Attempt:
>
> First attempt was I guessed 3 because it only adds up to 97 so I
> assumed 3 students knew none of them.
>
> Then I tried it out and got 27 for java, 21 for C and 25 for python,
> added those up and got 72. Minus 72 from 100 and got 28 as my final
> answer for students who know none.
>
> My teacher has no marking scheme for this question, this is a practice
> q. Anyone know the solution?

Comment: Try drawing a Venn diagram.

Answer (score 1):

Since no student knows both Java and Python, no student knows all three. Inclusion/exclusion then gives the number of students knowing at least one of the languages as
$$32+33+32-5-7-0+0=85$$
Subtracting from $100$ gives $15$ students not knowing any language.